# Treeview Check/Uncheck Parent Node

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I am using a `TreeView` control to list all my menus so that I can give access to each user. How I will forced the `parent node` to `check = true` when one or more `childnode` is checked by user?

I am using below code to check/uncheck all `child nodes` when `parent node` is checked.

```
private void treeView_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
 {
   if (e.Action != TreeViewAction.Unknown)
      {
        if (e.Node.Nodes.Count > 0)
          {
           CheckAllChildNodes(e.Node, e.Node.Checked);
           }
      }
 }

private void CheckAllChildNodes(TreeNode treeNode, bool nodeChecked)
 {
   foreach (TreeNode node in treeNode.Nodes)
   {
     node.Checked = nodeChecked;

     if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
       {                   
         this.CheckAllChildNodes(node, nodeChecked);                  
       }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select parent node if any single child node checked in treeview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234961/select-parent-node-if-any-single-child-node-checked-in-treeview)

Answer (score 1):

A TreeNode has a "Parent" property that should make it easy.
Untested code but should give you an idea.

```
private void CheckAllParentNodes(TreeNode treeNode, bool nodeChecked)
{
   TreeNode parentNode = treeNode.Parent;
   while (parentNode != null)
   {
     // check if parent has still checked child nodes
     if (parent.Nodes.Any(n => n.Checked)) return;

     parentNode.Checked = nodeChecked;
     parentNode = parentNode.Parent;
   }
}
```

Comment: About right, but you'll also need to handle the case when only one of the multiple child nodes is unchecked.

Comment: @defaultlocale good point. A check if any of the parents child nodes is checked should do the trick. Will try to edit a stub for this.